# How to tell R how to plot objects of a certain class?

Tags: r, class

I'm currently dealing with some objects that are a list of attributes that represents a statistical model. For example, let's say I have a matrix, a numeric vector and an integer.

```
myobj = list(amatrix = matrix(1:9,3,3),avector = c(1:3),aninteger = 1)
class(myobj) = 'myclass'
```

Suppose that, for some reason, I can create a plot that represents an object of this class. How can I make `plot(myobj)` recognizes that the object has the class `'myclass'`, and print it in the desired way, for example `image(myobj$amatrix)`?

I think the question is essentially how to 'modify' R's plot function so it knows how to handle a newly defined object class? Can I use functions of other packages like ggplot when executing this modification?

In a more general sense, how does functions that handle different classes of objects know how to act for each class?

I have little to none experience with classes in R, so even some simple guides about classes should be helpful.

Comment: You want to set an S3 method for your class. See [Hadley Wickham's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) for info. Basically you need define `plot.myclass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @emilliman you can define your own method:

```
myobj = list(amatrix = matrix(1:9,3,3),avector = c(1:3),aninteger = 1)
class(myobj) <- 'myclass'
plot.myclass <- function(x) image(x$amatrix)

methods(plot) # check the 4th element of 3rd line :) (list will differ depending on what packages are loaded)
#  [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts* plot.default        plot.dendrogram*    plot.density*       plot.ecdf          
#  [8] plot.factor*        plot.formula*       plot.function       plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*     plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*       
# [15] plot.lm*            plot.medpolish*     plot.mlm*           plot.myclass        plot.ppr*           plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*     
# [22] plot.profile.nls*   plot.R6*            plot.raster*        plot.spec*          plot.stepfun        plot.stl*           plot.table*        
# [29] plot.ts             plot.tskernel*      plot.TukeyHSD*

#and plot :
plot(myobj)
```